# Yii2 Update API with non primary key

Tags: php, api, yii, yii2

I am using `http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/` this link for making API in YII-2.

If I want to write custom api for updating values with non-primary key then how can it is possible?

Example `PATCH /countries/AU: update the country AU`

This is simple example of update countries with AU as primary key.

But I want to update the country by using code value then how it will possible.

Please help me...

Ref link : http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `code` CHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` CHAR(52) NOT NULL,
  `population` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Did you check the official Guide from Yii2? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

Comment: yes i checked it there is no such example

Comment: You should create your own action/override Yii's default action for this to work.